# NullPointerException in Spring Autowiring Repository

Tags: spring, jpa

I'm getting an NPE when I'm trying to auto wiring a Repository in my managed bean. This is my first project trying to use java configurations instead of xml configurations.

I'm not instantiating my self the repository and all the packages are in the spring context, even I can see in the log the instantiating of the repository.

Please, someone, give me a hand to figure out what's missing in my configuration

Using spring version 5.1.0.RELEASE and

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.genericdao</groupId>
            <artifactId>dao-hibernate</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

1) WebMvcConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan({
"com.config","com.gedificios",
})
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

   @Bean
   public InternalResourceViewResolver resolver() {
       InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new 
       InternalResourceViewResolver();
       resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
       resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
       resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
       return resolver;
   }

   @Override
   public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
       registry
           .addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
           .addResourceLocations("/resources/");
   }
}
```

2) PersistenceJPAConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource({"classpath:database.properties"})
@ComponentScan({"com.config","com.gedificios.core", "com.gedificios.persistence", "com.gedificios.view"})
@EntityScan("com.gedificios.persistence.entities")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.gedificios.core.repository")
public class PersistenceJPAConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    public PersistenceJPAConfig() {
        super();
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        final LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceXmlLocation("classpath*:WEB-INF/persistence.xml");
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceUnitName("persistenceUnit");
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());
        final HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setDatabasePlatform(env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        vendorAdapter.setShowSql(Boolean.getBoolean(env.getProperty("hibernate.show_sql")));
        vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(Boolean.getBoolean(env.getProperty("hibernate.generateDdl")));
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);

        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    final Properties additionalProperties() {
        final Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        return hibernateProperties;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        final DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class"));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("hibernate.connection.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("hibernate.connection.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("hibernate.connection.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }


    @Bean
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public  JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    public  JPAAnnotationMetadataUtil getMetadataUtil() {
        return new JPAAnnotationMetadataUtil();
    }

    @Bean
    public  JPASearchProcessor getJPASearchProcessor(JPAAnnotationMetadataUtil jpaAnnotationMetadataUtil) {
        return new JPASearchProcessor(jpaAnnotationMetadataUtil);
    }

}
```

3) Persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="persistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <non-jta-data-source/>
        <class>com.gedificios.persistence.entities.Contrato</class>
        <class>com.gedificios.persistence.entities.Edificio</class>
        <class>com.gedificios.persistence.entities.ubigeo.Pais</class>
        <class>com.gedificios.persistence.entities.ubigeo.Departamento</class>
        <class>com.gedificios.persistence.entities.ubigeo.Provincia</class>
        <class>com.gedificios.persistence.entities.ubigeo.Distrito</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="${hibernate.dialect}"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet" value="UTF-8"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate"/>
            <property name="hibernate.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults" value="false"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

4) PaisRepository

```
@Repository
public class PaisRepository extends BaseDAO<PaisDTO, String> {

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PaisRepository.class);

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        LOG.info("\n/***************** INICIALIZANDO REPOSITORY DE PAÍS /*****************\n");
    }

    public List<PaisDTO> getAllPaises() {
        List< PaisDTO> items = null;
        StringBuffer sql = new StringBuffer();
        sql.append(" SELECT ");
        sql.append(" P.id_pais \"idPais\" , ");
        sql.append(" P.nombre_pais  \"nombrePais\" ");
        sql.append(" FROM ubigeo_pais as P order by p.nombre_pais");
        System.out.println(sql);
        org.hibernate.Query<PaisDTO> query = em().unwrap(Session.class).createSQLQuery(sql.toString()).setResultTransformer(new JpaHbmBeanResultTransformer(PaisDTO.class));
        items = query.list();
        return items;
    }
}
```

4.1) Log evidence

```
06:24:50.197 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'getJPASearchProcessor'
06:24:50.198 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'getMetadataUtil'
06:24:50.198 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Autowiring by type from bean name 'getJPASearchProcessor' via factory method to bean named 'getMetadataUtil'
06:24:50.199 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO com.gedificios.core.repository.PaisRepository - 
/***************** INICIALIZANDO REPOSITORY DE PAÍS /*****************

06:24:50.201 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'DTOMapperServiceDozerImpl'
06:24:50.201 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG org.dozer.DozerInitializer - Tried to perform initialization when Dozer was already started.
06:24:50.201 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.dozer.DozerBeanMapper - Initializing a new instance of dozer bean mapper.
```

5) ManagedBean

```
@ManagedBean
@Scope("view")
@Component
public class AdminEdificios extends FindCrudBeanBase  {

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext applicationContext;
    @Autowired
    PaisRepository paisRepository;

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AdminEdificios.class);

    private List<PaisDTO> listaPaises;
    private List<DepartamentoDTO> listaDepartamentos;
    private List<ProvinciaDTO> listaDistritos;
    private List<DistritoDTO> listaProvincias;

    private String codigoPaisSeleccionado;
    private String codigoDepartamentoSeleccionado;
    private String codigoProvinciaSeleccionada;
    private String codigoDistritoSeleccionado;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        listaPaises = paisRepository.findAll();

        listaDepartamentos = new ArrayList<DepartamentoDTO>();
        listaDepartamentos.add(new DepartamentoDTO("001","001","Lima"));
    }

    ...

    getters & setters

}
```

The NPE is exactly here

```
listaPaises = paisRepository.findAll();
```

Comment: Seems like you are mixing Spring beans with managed JSF Beans. Could try to remove `@ManagedBean` from AdminEdificios?

Comment: If I remove `@ManagedBean` the project starts but the repository does not retrieve any data

Comment: But you fixed the NPE?